# What are these scope changes in a bash script doing?

Tags: bash

If you have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  x=foo
  { echo $x }
)
```

What is the significance of the parentheses and braces? What are these constructs known as? What properties do they have? What are they used for etc.?

Answer (score 7):

The commands enclosed in round parentheses `(...)` are run in a subshell. They inherit the environment from the parent shell, but any changes they make isn't propagated back to the parent.

`{ echo $x }` is wrong, there's a missing `;` before the closing `}`. Commands run in `{ ... }` are run in the context of the current shell, it's usually used when you need to redirect output of several commands, e.g.

```sh
{
    echo 1
    echo 2
} > log
```

Note that the final `;` is not needed if there's a newline in its place.

Answer (score 3):

re: the (curly) braces (`{...}`) ... from the man pages for `bash`:

> ```
>    { list; }
>           list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list  must  be  termi‐
>           nated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.  The return
>           status is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and  ),
>           {  and  } are reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to
>           be recognized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from
>           list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.
> ```

The provided example of a *single* command inside braces (`{ echo $x }`), setting aside the syntax issue, doesn't make much sense (ie, it's not any different than `echo $x`).

One [example from linux.com](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/all-about-curly-braces-bash/):

```
$ { echo "I found all these PNGs:"; find . -iname "*.png"; echo "Within this bunch of files:"; ls; } > PNGs.txt

# or

$ { echo "I found all these PNGs:"
find . -iname "*.png"
echo "Within this bunch of files:"
ls
} > PNGs.txt
```

Here the `{...}` groups all of the output together so that only a single `> PNGs.txt` is required to send the output from all 4x commands to the file `PNGs.txt`.

Without the `{...}` you would need:

```
$ echo "I found all these PNGs:"     >  PNGs.txt
$ find . -iname "*.png"              >> PNGs.txt
$ echo "Within this bunch of files:" >> PNGs.txt
$ ls                                 >> PNGs.txt
```

---

For the following set of commands the `(...)` and `{...}` generate the same result (all output sent to file `PNGs.txt`) ...

```
{ echo "I found all these PNGs:"; find . -iname "*.png"; echo "Within this bunch of files:"; ls; } > PNGs.txt

( echo "I found all these PNGs:"; find . -iname "*.png"; echo "Within this bunch of files:"; ls; ) > PNGs.txt
```

... with the 2nd option incurring the additional overhead of spawning a subshell.

With the following example we see the different effects of execution in the current/parent shell vs execution in the subshell:

```
$ { x=5 ; }           # defined in current/parent shell
$ ( x=7 ; )           # defined in subshell, not visible to parent; `;` is optional
$ echo $x
5
```