# What is the difference between ( ... ) and { ... } in bash

Tags: bash

In bash, are there any differences between opting to use `( ... )` or `{ ... }`, as in my test case, both of these product the same expected result:

```sh
# using round brackets
(
    echo 'hello'
    echo 'world'
) | rev
```

```sh
# using squiggly brackets
{
    echo 'hello'
    echo 'world'
} | rev
```

```
# result:
olleh
dlrow
```

Perhaps this test case in a condition where they are the same, however are factors where I would opt for one syntax over the other?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a difference between `( )` `{ }` _in a pipeline_ `<here> | something`, or in general?

Comment: both / in general — I've rephrased to try and make this more clear

Comment: Then https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping would explain it for you? And https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines

Comment: Read the bash manual.

Comment: "_however are factors where I would opt for one syntax over the other_" - I use `( ... ) > result &` `pid=$!` if I want to start some heavy processing in the background while continuing the main flow. When I need the result, I can do `wait $pid` and then read `result`. Afaik, that's not possible with `{ ... }` - which if I'm correct usually gives a thread id back in `$!` that you can't `wait` for.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `Afaik, that's not possible with { ... }` could you give an example? There should be no difference...  `{ sleep 5; } & wait $!` surely works.

Comment: @KamilCuk You're correct. I used the wrong format. [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to the rescue (as always) :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are these scope changes in a bash script doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046250)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are there any differences between opting to use ( ... ) or { ... }

Yes, one spawns a subshell the other executes commands in [current execution environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html).

> however are factors where I would opt for one syntax over the other?

Sure - use `()` when you want to spawn a subshell.

> In bash, are there any differences between these two code blocks:

(I think, but I'm not 100% sure) that no. The left side of a pipeline is spawned in a subshell. Then Bash detects that `(...)` is a single only expression on the left side, so Bash optimizes and does not spawn a subshell and just executes the content of the second list of commands and does not spawn a second subshell, so both should result in exactly the same "count of subshell" being spawned. This is an "optimization", the same way `( ( ( ( ( ( echo ) ) ) ) ) )` can be just one subshell.